# Calculating proportion with negative float values

Tags: c++, math, optimization

I'd like to know if there's any way in C++ to calculate a proportion involving possibily negative values in both vars and extremes.

My goal is to sync a float text input widget with fixed extremes ( eg the user can input any double value between A (min) and B (max) with A,B=any_constant_real_number ) with a slider who can only slide between 0 and 100 ( to simplify ).

If A and B are positive everything is trivial. as 
val_slider = ((val_textin-A)*100)/(B-A)

but as A and B can be assumed real it looks to me the only possibility is to use several if/cases, or huge formulas involving a lot of abs() and checks over 0-divisions, whose are quite error prone and very cost intense compared to such an easy task.

Is there any faster and shorter way to achieve the same in c/c++/stl?

Pardon my bad english. Any hint? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your formula should work fine with negative values of `A` and `B` as well, as log as `A < B`.

Example, if you want the user to be able to enter values from -100 to 100, and map these to a slider which goes from 0 - 100, when the user enters -90 you get:

```
((-90 - A) * 100) / (B - A) = ((-90 - (-100)) * 100) / (100 - (-100)) 
                            = 10 * 100 / 200
                            = 5
```

An input value of 50 results in a slider value of:

```
((50 - A) * 100) / (B - A) = ((50 - (-100)) * 100) / (100 - (-100)) 
                           = 150 * 100 / 200
                           = 75
```

Comment: Omg, sorry, way to late here. i gotta stop coding during night. I actually made a silly mistake while testing.  thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know C++, but I do know Math, so try:

```
val_slider = 100 * ( val_textin - A ) / ( B - A )
```

Hey wait. That's exactly what you have. Test case..

A=-200, B=+200, val_texin = 100 (75% of bar, right?)

val_slider = 100 * ( 100 - -200 ) / ( 200 - - 200 )
= ( 300 ) / ( 400 ) * 100
= 75

See, you got it right. The only thing that COULD happen is B==A, but that can't be accounted for with math and requires a single IF. If they are equal, val_slider is exactly B (or A, as they are equal).